# 'Green' alternative to TSP for cleaning walls for paint preparation

Tags: paint, cleaning, green

Based on some of my cursory research, TSP seems to be bad for the environment and is toxic. So just to play it on the safe side I want to see what people have used that is effective for preparing walls for painting.

TSP is suppose to clean and degrease the walls. What other things do that?
Simple Green(?), vinegar, etc.

I've seen substitutes out there but I want to know what works the best and gives the same results as TSP.

Comment: Krud Cutter and Borax come to mind

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy but it provides a piece of mind. I've just been using 3M sponges with scrub-pads and [Meyers Household Cleaner](http://www.mrsmeyers.com/product/household-cleaners/).

I've peeled the wallpaper in three rooms and followed up with a good scrub. Let it Dry. Then spackle and sand spots (120 or finer) that need it. Let that Dry. Then sand patches and lightly sand whole wall. Wipe down with a damp sponge rinsing out dust as you go. Let Dry. Paint with two coats.

Answer (score 0):

TSP sold nowdays is actually a TSP substitute. The labeling on the container does not make it blatantly obvious, but it is there, TSP: in bold letters, substitute: in small font, below TSP.
 It works much like the real stuff, but is much safer to use.